# How to scroll to a given line number, TextView inside ScrollView

Tags: java, android, textview, scrollview

I have a TextView inside a ScrollView. I want to scroll the text so that a known line number is more or less centered vertically. This should not be difficult, but it seems to be so. I have not seen any posts or tutorials that address specifically this problem of scrolling to a given line number.

After my research i think it should work like this ...

```
scroller.scrollTo(0, lineNumb * html.getLineHeight());
```

where scroller is the R.Id of the ScrollView and html is the TextView, and lineNumb is obvously the line number, but the text does not move.

I have put it into a runnable, but still no joy ...

```
scroller.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    scroller.scrollTo(0, lineNumb * html.getLineHeight());}});
```

I spent the whole day trying to figure this out studying many posts, tutorials, etc but am at a dead end. I must be missing something that is quite simple. Hope you can help.

***Mick***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scroll `textView` inside `ScrollView` by line number like that.

```
textView.setText(text);
final int lineNumber = 20;
scroller.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int y = textView.getLayout().getLineTop(lineNumber);
        scroller.scrollTo(0, y);
    }
});
```

Additionally, you can scroll only `textView` without wrapping `scrollView`.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:padding="16dp"/>
```

To scroll `textView` :

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
final int lineNumber = 20
textView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int y = textView.getLayout().getLineTop(lineNumber);
        textView.scrollTo(0, y);
    }
});
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: When your code would not work i checked my xml file - the TextView was not within the ScrollView!  :(  I had put it in correctly to begin but i think it got moved when i was cleaning up using the Design view.

I am pleased to know that i do not need the scrollview - simpler is always better :)